# CAShapeLayer groove path

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I wanted to make a white color view with a triangle shaped pointer being grooved inside like this:

[image]

**As shown in the image above, goal is to create a "rounded groove" inset into the `white`view**

```
    let pointerRadius:CGFloat = 4
    pointerLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    pointerLayer.path = pointerPathForContentSize(contentSize: bounds.size).cgPath
    pointerLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    pointerLayer.lineWidth = 2*pointerRadius
    pointerLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    pointerLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    pointerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    layer.addSublayer(pointerLayer)
```

But what I get is this:

[image]

But,if I set the stroke color to white

```
pointerLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

[image]
In the groove I wanted to have a `rounded edge` in bottom (just like in the first pic) which no more remains visible when fillColor and strokeColor get matched (both white).
How can I fix it? 
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Here is the code for pointer path:

```
private func pointerPathForContentSize(contentSize: CGSize) -> UIBezierPath
{
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height)

    let width:CGFloat = 20
    let height:CGFloat = 20

    let path = UIBezierPath()


    let startX:CGFloat = 50
    let startY:CGFloat = rect.minY
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: startX , y: startY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (startX + width*0.5), y: startY + height))


    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (startX + width), y: startY))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))


    path.close()
    return path
}
```

Comment: Layer strokes are **inside** views, not outside them; that’s why you don’t see the groove when the line is white.

Comment: so how can I  fix it?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What's the problem? What's wrong with the results you're getting? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the groove has got a rounded edge in bottom, it no more remains visible when fillColor and strokeColor get matched.

Comment: I end up with a pointed groove at the end

Comment: @matt I have added some more details to the question.

Comment: So the goal is to create a "rounded groove" inset into a view? Or is it about a "rounded pointer" extending from a view? Is this about the blue upper view or the white lower view?

Comment: Sry for unclear question. it is about the white lower view, and rounded pointer inset into the view

Comment: @matt I have added more details, hope it will be more clear now.

Comment: I can help you do that, but don't you think that's rather an odd thing to do? The interface looks to me like a blue-view-with-a-pointer (or an image-view-with-a-pointer). Wouldn't you rather add the pointer to the blue view / image view? Like a caption balloon? Like this, but with the pointer more rounded: https://github.com/mattneub/MessageBubble Isn't that what you really want?

Comment: Actually, the blue view will be extending way down behind the white view (it will play a video). The pointer will act as a selector to 2 tabs in the white view

Comment: @matt Can u pls point me in right direction to achieve this?

Comment: Well, there are two ways I can think of. The obvious way, if you want to round the bottom of the shape, is to round the bottom of the shape. Instead of drawing two lines that meet at a sharp V, draw a line, an arc, and another line.

Comment: I have tried drawing a line, an arc, and another line. The problem I am not sure is with angle or not but it makes a cup like shape in  bottom rather than joining the lines. I have used .'pi' and '0' radians

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already outlined the shape you want by stroking the path, I think the simplest solution is probably to use the stroked and filled path as a mask.

For example, here is a rectangular red view:

[image]

And here is the same red view with the notch cut out of the top. This seems to be the sort of thing you're after:

[image]

What I did there was to mask the red view with a special mask view that draws the notch using `.clear` blend mode:

```
class MaskView : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        self.isOpaque = false
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        con.fill(self.bounds)
        con.setBlendMode(.clear)
        con.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:-4))
        con.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:100, y:-4))
        con.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:110, y:15))
        con.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:120, y:-4))
        con.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.maxX, y:-4))
        con.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.maxX, y:-20))
        con.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y:-20))
        con.closePath()
        con.setLineJoin(.round)
        con.setLineWidth(10)
        con.drawPath(using: .fillStroke) // stroke it and fill it
    }
}
```

So then when I'm ready to cut out the notch on the red view, I just say:

```
self.redView.mask = MaskView(frame:self.redView.bounds)
```

Comment: Thank you for ur time and effort! can I use the `replacePathWithStrokedPath` with CAShapeLayer or UIBezierPath ? or  working in `drawRect` is the only possible way now?

Comment: Actually, I'm an idiot. You don't need the `replacePathWithStrokedPath` at all. You just need the mask idea. Revised my code.

Comment: Although it is working nicely, I am wondering y only the groove got curved but not other lines ?

Comment: Because I shoved the whole mask drawing up so that it wouldn't overlap the view and cut off its top. That is what the `-4` in my code is about. You could move it back down to `0` but this would chop off some of the top of the red view. Up to you.